# Date picker validation in APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am new to APEX environment and need to know the ways to perform validation on date picker items. On Apex page I have 2 date pickers , start date and end date.
Selecting the start and end date I'm able to get the required data on page but need to add some validations in date pickers items, say e.g I need to add validation rules for :

- Start date should be less than End date
- Start date should not be greater than sysdate
- One should not be able to enter invalid date format.

Can anyone please share some good examples and links to add above validations on date picker items on  APEX5.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:::NO::P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:11399,2) you have a good basic tutorial (fist from a series of 4). Chapter 7, Creating Validations, contains validation examples.

For the other 3 tutorials from this series check the [Oracle Learning Library](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:2:0:force_query::2:p2_group_id,p2_product_id,P2_RELEASE_ID:1000,2039,477)

Comment: Those first two links are dead now.

Comment: Yea.. Oracle really loves changing there links. I have updated the dead links. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the default value for ***Start Date*** --> `SYSDATE`

For the ***End date***, you can make a `DA` (*Dynamic Action*) that will take `start` and ***disable*** all dates lower than the one you picked for Start date.