# Date picker validation not working in Apex 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

On APEX 5.0, I  tried to add date validation in "From" date of my form to show errors on page when From date entered is today's date.  On processing page I created new validation name with following settings. With below settings still the validation is not working, could you please suggest where I am doing wrong.

`Type -> PL/SQL expression 2)PL/SQL expression ->  to_char(to_date(:P5_NEW_8,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS') < to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS')` where `P5_NEW_8` is the "From" date picker item where date entered is of format `YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS`.

Error message -> From: date needs to before today

Associated Item -> `P5_NEW_8`

Condition -> When Button Pressed ->  `New_7`

`New_7` button has a dynamic action to display result on my bar chart.

Condition Type -> Request is contained in Value

Value ->  Create, Save

Comment: How is it not working?is there an error showing?is the buttong not displaying?please be detailed about your problem.thanks

Comment: when I click on the button for which the condition is "When button pressed" ,the validation should occur for the date picker item which is not happening.

Comment: just try removing the condition type under the dynamic action, so you can submit the page.just to see whether the validation is working

Comment: I removed "Request is contained in Value" from condition type but still the validation is not working. what else shall I check?

Comment: Have you tried setting the action of the button to submit page?

Comment: I have the button action as dynamic action because there are multiple regions on same page, for one of my region where I need to enter the start date and end date , as soon as I fill these dates and press the submit button - only that particular region is refreshed to display new values on the bar chart hence I cannot use submit page action since I donot want to refresh whole page ,  I just want to refresh a particular region along with validation that if start_date entered is today's date then an error shall be thrown to the user.In this scenario how to achieve the validation?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but I dont know if the validation will run if you will prevent the whole page from submitting.I tried adding another action on the button which is refresh a region, but the validation is not working for me.try doing that to your page.see if that works for you.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I want the date validation without refreshing whole page, is there a way if this can be achieved?

Comment: Please read my comment above carefully, there is a way to refresh a region.But i dont know if that will fix your problem. To do that, you have to add true action to your button, set it on refresh, then select affected element and choose the region you want to refresh when the button is clicked.It will refresh the region selected but i dont know if the validation will work.

Comment: can you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972550/date-picker-validation-in-apex-5-0

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to cast the dates to varchar2,  by doing that you are doing string comparison i.e. 12-01-2010 is larger then 02-09-2016, not date comparison.

So use instead a simpler:  `to_date(:P5_NEW_8,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS') < sysdate`